# check box change event not firing when checked property set from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

When I manually check/uncheck checkboxes,

`$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){})` fires perfectly.

But when I set the checked property inside code, this event handler is not get executed.

**Markup:**

```
    <li><input id="p-Client-Management" type="checkbox" name="selectedMenuItem" value="Client Management">Client Management</input>
        <ul>
           <li><input class="parent-p-Client-Management" type="checkbox" name="selectedMenuItem" value="Demo Client">Demo Client</input></li>
           <li><input class="parent-p-Client-Management" type="checkbox" name="selectedMenuItem" value="Basic Clients">Basic Clients</input></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    **Event handler :**

    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');

                    if(id){  
                        console.log("parent found -> "+id);
                        var children = $('.parent-'+id);
                        console.log("children of "+id+" -> "+children.length);
                        for(var i = 0; i<children.length; i++){
                            children[i].checked = document.getElementById(id).checked;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if(this.checked){
                            console.log("Child is checked");
                            var suffix = $(this).attr('class').split("-")[2];
                            document.getElementById('p-'+suffix).checked = true;
                        }

});
```

I have `id` for the parent checkbox and `class` for child checkboxes. When parent checkbox is checked, the `if` block will get executed showingconsole output *parent found*. When child is checked, the else block will get executed showing console output *Child is checked*. What I want is, on checking parent manually, the child's `else` block will also get executed as their checked property is set with the parent and providing output *Child is checked*

Comment: Is this supposed to be happening on page load? If so, wrap your code in `$(function () { ... });`. You'd also have to take your `if (this.checked)` function out of your input change scope.

Answer (score 1):

Programatically changing the value/checked status of an element won't trigger the change handler, but you can trigger them manually by using `.trigger('change')` or by using the short hand `.change()`

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    if (id) {
        console.log("parent found -> " + id);
        var children = $('.parent-' + id);
        console.log("children of " + id + " -> " + children.length);

        if (children.length) {
            children[this.checked ? 'not' : 'filter'](':checked').prop('checked', this.checked).change()
        }
    } else {
        if (this.checked) {
            console.log("Child is checked");
            var suffix = $(this).attr('class').split("-")[2];
            $('#p-' + suffix).not(':checked').prop('checked', true).change();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why the `change` event is not triggered for the checkbox when it is checked/unchecked using JavaScript?

Comment: events are triggered only when a user initiates it... you can manually trigger event... `$(checkbox).prop('checked', true).trigger('change')`

Comment: And if I don't use jQuery? `checkboxElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpdfukyc/7/)

```
  $('input[type=checkbox]').unbind('change').change(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if(id=="p-Client-Management"){  
            console.log("parent found -> "+id);
            var childrens = $('.parent-'+id);
            var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
            childrens.prop('checked', isChecked);
            childrens.change();
        } else{
            console.log("Child is checked");

        }                
    });
```